# Ionic 3 Deeplinking - launch app from URL

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, deep-linking

I'm developing a cross platform app using Ionic and when trying to achieve deeplinking, I installed an Ionic Native plugin called **Deeplinks**

I ran these comands:

```
ionic cordova plugin add ionic-plugin-deeplinks --variable URL_SCHEME=roor --variable DEEPLINK_SCHEME=http --variable DEEPLINK_HOST=roor.com --variable ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX=/

npm install --save @ionic-native/deeplinks
```

For testing, I made a codepen and added the following html

```
<h3>
  <a href="roor://roor.com">scheme</a>
</h3>

<h3>
  <a href="http://www.roor.com">url</a>
</h3>
```

My app did launch when clicking on **scheme** but nothing happened when clicking on **url**.

How can I be able to open my app from a **URL**

I also found an article about deeplinking: https://blog.ionicframework.com/deeplinking-in-ionic-apps/

which states that

> To configure iOS and Android, we need to enable Universal Links for
>   iOS, and App Links for Android (6.0+). This process is primarily done
>   on the server side of your website. You’ll publish a specific json
>   file for iOS and one for Android, ensure your site is using HTTPS, and
>   then configure your app to open in response to links to that domain.

But I'm not sure about what json file I should publish to enable deeplinknig from a URL?

Comment: Seems like those configs for ios and android are each platform specific and guidance should come from google's developer pages and apple dev pages accordingly. Did you try to follow those hyperlinks and read instructions for the links?

Comment: have you got solution?

Comment: Had the same issue. I suppose your `DEEPLINK_SCHEME` is `https`, which means you should use `https://www.roor.com`

Answer (score 0):

You have to publish the `./static/.well-known/assetlinks.json` file to your server to work with android, and the `./static/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` for iOS.

Their names are confusing DEEPLINK_SCHEME is for Universal/App Links over HTTPS, while URL_SCHEME is for the old custom schemes like myapp://