# Can I open my ionic app from another app?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have the following problem.
Imagine that I have another apk in react navie or flutter and I want that when I click on a certain button my ionic application opens and if the person doesn’t have the apk it goes to the playstore to download it.
Is it possible to do that?

Comment: You want to open your app through deeplinks. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52907211/ionic-3-deeplinking-launch-app-from-url and https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/deeplinks

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Dynamic Link  can fit your requirements, have look into it
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-dynamic-links

Official video from Firebase for dynamic link: https://youtu.be/zra2DCd0DnY

You can customize the dynamic link as for your requirements. You can also customize the link to navigate to play store and searching for your particular app when even the app is not present in a Android device.